# How to Convert event object to string in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get which event is occured ::

```
function getEvent(){
    alert(window.event);
}
```

I am getting below event object. I want it in string to compare. if event onclick event then I want to do the action. how can I get it in string? or how can I convert event object to string?

```
[object MouseEvent]
```

Comment: Why do you need this? Can you give an example?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the type property. `window.event.type`

Comment: +1 for you. I am getting "TypeError: window.event is undefined"  when I am try to use  alert(window.event.type ) in Mozilla browser, Its working well with Google Chrome.

Comment: The error is pretty self explanatory, window.event is not defined. Firefox handles events slightly differently from chrome. You should change your code to `function getEvent(e){alert(e.type);}`

Comment: After using your code    function getEvent(e){alert(e.type);} I am getting     "ReferenceError: e is not defined". call of getEvent function is     getEvent(event);

Answer (score 3):

You'd probably want:

```
function getEvent(){
    alert(window.event.type);
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/event.type

Answer (score 1):

you can easily get it by `type` like this

```
function getEvent(){
    alert(window.event.type);
}
```

More info here

http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_access.html

http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_properties.html

Answer (score 1):

use the `type` property to read out the type:

```
function getEvent(){
    alert(window.event.type);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `event.type` property, for example

```
<div id="a" onclick="alert(event.type)">Click This</div>

<div id="b">And This</div>​
```

**Javascript**:

```
var func = $('#a').attr('onclick');
$('#b').mouseover(function(e) {
    func(e)
});
```

**DEMO**: http://jsfiddle.net/4tLms/
​

Comment: I've just tested it and working fine. Do you have javascript turned on?